# How to combine Self-signed SSL certificate and alltrusted context in Glide

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit2, okhttp, android-glide

There is a server behind https that gives resources using a self-signed certificate. I'm using okhttp/retrofit and handshake passes successfully, so any resources are successfully obtained. But as soon as I make a request for an image with the same Glide, but from a different server, which is also encrypted with https, but already with a DIFFERENT certificate, I logically get "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ". Unfortunatelly, i have no way to add certificates for each server, the links i'll get are dynamically.

Due to the lot of posts on SO and Google Docs, wrote two functions in my InetHelper class that create two different OkHTTPClients - one with a self-signed certificate, the other for "AllTrusted", like:

```
            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = getSSLOKHttpBuilder();
            okClient = builder.build();

            OkHttpClient.Builder builderFree = getAllTrustedSSLOKHttpBuilder();
            okAllTrustedClient = builderFree.build();
```

now, we could use the okAllTrustedClient only in Glide, using Glide in okHttp integration, but we have to init the Glide client with AllTrustedClient btw:

```
@GlideModule
public final class OkHttpGlideModule extends LibraryGlideModule {

    private static OkHttpClient okGlideClient = InetHelper.getAllTrustedClient();

    public static void setOkClient(OkHttpClient client) {
        okGlideClient = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {

        super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry);
        registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class,
                new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(okGlideClient));
    }
}
```

but then it will be applied for all resources received via Glide. And on-demand using of the setOkClient function from the code above to switch OkHttpClient clients, depending on the link, does not work, apparently due to the fact that Glide is initialized once. I would like to use AllTrusted via Glide only for links that do not have registered certificates. What is the best way to proceed in this case?
Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of googling and bumptech docs/examples reading, i have found my bad - just change the inherited class and client reference:

```
@GlideModule
public final class OkHttpGlideModule extends LibraryGlideModule
```

to

```
@GlideModule
public final class OkHttpGlideModule extends AppGlideModule

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        OkHttpClient okGlideClient = InetHelper.getAllTrustedClient();
        registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class,
                new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(okGlideClient));
    }
```

and now it works, but then you can't easiely switch between okHttp clients you have overriden before  (setOkClient method in my case don't work). If somebody got it "why?", please explain it in comments. Thanks.

Hope it will somebody help.

Comment: Please let me know where I have to use in code, I means where I we use `OkHttpGlideModule` in our app's code?